# Re-drilling into existing hole in plasterboard/breeze block

Tags: repair, drywall, drill, brick

I live in the UK. I drilled a hole to hang a mirror and it’s slightly off, I’d like to shift it over to a new location, the new location will be half over the old hole.

So I’d like to fill the existing hole but fill it to be able to bear the weight of a heavy mirror still.

It’s plasterboard and breeze block as it’s an external facing wall.

How can I fill the hole to a strength strong enough to bear load?

Thanks!

Comment: A picture would be worth a thousand words.

Comment: Is there a void in the wall behind the hole or do you have wood structure ? What is the method that the mirror hangs on, Wire or clips etc ?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the term breeze block, is this plasterboard over cinder block or concrete blocks?

Comment: Breeze blocks are cinder or clinker type blocks, common in the UK. Medium weight and they take a plug and screw rather well.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a pair of holes. I often do this for larger pictures and mirrors, it spreads the load over two fixings and helps stabilisation, no tipping out of plumb or level when the door slams or such like.

Re. the original hole, you're going to struggle to fill it well enough to be able to drill half of it out again, especially if it's more than 50mm deep. Difficult to picture half a hole making such a difference without seeing the location.